# Resolving version conflicts for UpdateByQuery in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to implement UpdateByQuery on large dataset, on a server which is updated by various nodes very frequently. This results in version control issues for a lot of documents. Also, retry_on_conflict is not the solution I am looking for, as I have already implemented it,and still I lose some documents.

Is there a way,using scripts or otherwise,that allows me to update documents even if specified version is less than current version ?
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The question is not clear, could you put the snapshot or code that you have already tried. It will be helpful to understand the problem more clearly

Comment: Its a simple UpdateByQuery that uses a script. The only issue I get is that some records are not updated.Their updation fails , with an error like - version_conflict:30. I cuurently don't have that system on which the query was executed,hence unable to post screenshot. Though ,query looks something like this -   `POST test1/_update_by_query?wait_for_completion=false
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.index+=10"
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "index": {
        "value": "3"
      }
    }
  }
}`